# What is the frequency at which meaningful data can be sent?

Tags: signal, frequency

Excuse my poor use of accurate terminology, in advance.

- Is it possible to hear anything meaningful on a 1Hz signal? Are there any 1Hz signals?
- What frequencies can you hear natural phenomena?
- At what frequency does a signal become useful for transmitting data? Why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design but is a series of questions about human physiology.

Comment: No, you've missed the point. I'm talking about data transmission and signals.

Comment: I would suggest removing the references to sound and re-focus the question on RF communication. You seem to be more interested in understanding the limitations of using a low-frequency carrier signal than in using sound as a medium, per se.

Answer (score 1):

The typical human ear can hear in the range of around 20Hz to 22kHz, this range gets narrower with age and hearing damage. Some animals can hear lower, but probably not 1Hz. Certainly a microphone could be designed to detect 1Hz sound and thus a signal could be modulated upon that, however, it would be very low data rate because the bandwidth can not be greater than the carrier frequency. Seismologists study the frequency range around 1Hz (see image below from Columbia University). The site from where this image was taken provides some additional info at: http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/res/pi/sounds-of-seismology/02_snd.shift.primer/index_2_sndshift.html
[image: Hearing &seismology range]

Disclaimer: The upper limit of the range of human hearing in this graphic appears to be off by about 1 decade (it should be higher).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to hear anything meaningful on a 1Hz signal?

1 Hz signal is not audible to human ear.

> Are there any 1Hz signals?

Yes. Any sinusoidal oscillation of time period 1 second is a 1Hz signal.

> What frequencies can you hear natural phenomena?

Human beings can hear an audible range 20Hz~20kHz.

> At what frequency does a signal become useful for transmitting data? Why?

I can not say at what frequency does a signal become useful for transmitting data. Because it depends on the property of data to be transmitted, allowable noise level at the receiver, size of antenna etc.